# Is there a way to do some async url look up while clicking the link?

Tags: html

We have a regular link. And we want it to behave exactly like any normal link.

Except one thing.

When the link is clicked, we want the browser to make a request to a different URL so we can track the click, then open the link's URL.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Bind a eventhandler on the click, do whatever you feel like..
Track the Url and redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try AJAX to fetch the URL and after that load the new page with `loadUrl('http://somesite.com')`

Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: I sort of know that I got to use ajax. I suppose I should put something in onclick and return true or something.

Comment: That's good enough for me. I think I will select this if you add more info. Like sample code.